# Spheres are "spherical", and cylinders are "cylindrical". What would a torus then be?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, mathematics, shapes

My thoughts would be to refer to a torus as being "torical", though I can't seem to find any use of that word anywhere. Is there a proper word for describing an object that has a similar shape to that of a torus?

For reference: a torus

[image]

Comment: @Hellion — please make this into an answer with supporting reference or link. That way it can be up or down voted and accepted by the poster. That's how SE is meant to work.

Comment: @David I am actually familiar with the SE model.  :-)  I generally don't post an answer to a question i believe will be closed, but if the answer is apparent I often post it as a comment so the questioner doesn't go away completely empty-handed.

Comment: @Hellion — But if others see you ignoring the injunction that appears on openening the comment box they too will think that they are justified in doing so, breaking the SE model. If you believe a question is off-topic you can just ignore it. If you wish to help people, then you can just as well provide a justified and votable answer (like MDHunter), even if the question may later be removed. Or you could explain to the poster that you believe the question to be off-topic and point him to sources where he can find an answer. You would be helping him more by helping him to help himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word [toroidal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toroidal) means "of, relating to, or shaped like a torus or toroid" according to Merriam-Webster. If you want to describe something's being doughnut shaped, that's your best bet.

Comment: Or you can always use "doughnut shaped".

Comment: Note that the identical definition is also given for [toric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toric) in MW.

Comment: Nah. Doughnuts are spheroid and filled with jam. Or, bizarrely, custard.

Comment: That would correspond to *spheroidal* and *cylindroidal*, not *spherical* and *cylindrical*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Those are bismarcks.  Ask the fox.